# Cell grouping for Apache POI: is there a way to get the plus at the top instead of the bottom?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm using Apache POI and I want to group some cells together. However, the expansion icon shows up [1 cell below](http://imgur.com/PS6XC6u) instead of [1 cell above](http://imgur.com/qIWmrf4). Is there any way to fix this?

In excel, I would click on the "outline" advance options and uncheck the "Summary rows below detail" option to fix this issue usually. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use below method on Sheet/XSSFSheet

```
sheet.setRowSumsBelow(false);
```